# Google analytic API to show count of Android + iOS users

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

I have an application which is deployed on both iOS and Android.

Now I wanna see how many android and iOS users I have in my application using their API.  It doesn't really matter which activities are the most viewed or etc, but what I want is to know:

> How many android users do I have
>
> How many iOS users do I have?

is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible in Google Analytics screen there is a list of tabs available, in that select acquisition-> New users -> you can get operating system. There they separated the operating system with no of new users

Comment: @Madhu Thanks for your reply, yea I saw that page but I'm kinda lost in order to extract that info from their api because I have to show that information on a graph on a website. Do you know how can I extract all that OS information from that page?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics you can set Filter 
**Admin->ViewSettings->Filter**
and set filter on Operating System parameter

Edit : 
Admin->ViewSettings->Filter->New Filter[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about how to use that filter in order to get the required data from the API??

Comment: see my answer edit. and keep in mind filter will not reflect instantly it will be applied on new data which will come in future.